# RegEx matching in HTML string

Tags: android, regex

Im facing this problem:

I have a string containing some weird HTML stuff, like

```
String result = "<div id=\"foo\"><div class=\"bar\">xyz</div><div id=\"alert\"><strong>Foo Bar 2% foobar.</strong></div></div>"
```

(this string is even bigger than in this example. It contains a whole webpage.)

My problem is now:

1. Find the line `<div id="alert"><strong>Foo Bar 2% foobar.</strong></div>`
2. extract the number (digit) `2` out there (this could be `[0-9]{1,3}`).

My attempt:

```
String pattern = "<div id=\"alert\"><strong>(.+) (\\d{1,3})% (.+)</strong></div>";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(result);
while(matcher.find()) {
    Log.i(TAG, "" + matcher.group();
}
```

But this does not throw the expected result (I would except: `2`).

I mainly develop in PHP, so there it is no problem to handle (`preg_match`), but I don't know how to do this in Java.

Thanks!

Comment: you can jsoup to extract content from the tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: `regex` is your problem..don't use it..use html parser to extract div tag's values and then extract digits using regex

Comment: @Raghunandan Jsoup sounds interesting. Maybe I could get it working ;-)

Comment: @Anirudh Yeah, thought so too, but I could not get a better idea for matching this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jsoup to extract content from html tags. Then you can use regex on the string extracted.

Download jsoup from

http://jsoup.org/download.

```
    String url = "<div id=\"foo\"><div class=\"bar\">xyz</div><div id=\"alert\"><strong>Foo Bar 2% foobar.</strong></div></div>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url);  
    Elements elements = doc.select("strong");
    String s= elements.text();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{1,3}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s); 
    while (m.find()) {
       String result =m.group();
    }
```